# How to assign the previous row value to next row

Tags: sql-server

```
Date       Starting      Ending

10/01/2010      0            100
10/02/2010     100           200
10/03/2010     200           300
10/04/2010     300             0   

the table has only one column that is ending and i need the output similar to one shown above and using sqlserver 2005
```

Comment: What does your table structure look like?  Also, what version of SQL Server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming a table called `SampleData`, and columns called `Date` and `Starting`, you can do this to query the table:

```
SELECT S1.Date, S1.Starting, ISNULL(S2.Starting, 0) as Ending
FROM SampleData S1
LEFT OUTER JOIN
(
    SELECT *
    FROM SampleData
) S2
ON DATEADD(d, 1, S1.Date) = S2.Date
```

Which will return:

```
Date       Starting      Ending

10/01/2010      0            100
10/02/2010     100           200
10/03/2010     200           300
10/04/2010     300             0
```

If you want to update the table instead, you can do the following:

```
UPDATE SampleData
SET Starting = Ending
FROM SampleData S3 
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT S1.Date, ISNULL(S2.Starting, 0) as Ending
    FROM SampleData S1
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
    (
        SELECT *
        FROM SampleData
    ) S2
    ON DATEADD(d, 1, S1.Date) = S2.Date
) S4 ON S3.Date = S4.Date
```

Answer (score 2):

May not be the best solution but following would work if its one time operation and performance is not a concern

CREATE FUNCTION GetPreviousVal
(
    @PrevVal int
)
RETURNS int
AS
BEGIN

```
DECLARE @ReturnVal INT

SELECT TOP 1 @ReturnVal = Ending 
FROM RowVal
WHERE Ending < @PrevVal
ORDER BY Ending DESC


RETURN @ReturnVal
```

END

GO

Now, use above function to update your data

```
UPDATE RowVal
SET Starting = ISNULL(dbo.GetPreviousVal(Ending),0)
```